# '^@' notation in Can JS, while passing data to components

Tags: javascript, canjs

In Can JS, I have seen using a notation '^@', with the values passed to another Component.
For example: 
if sample is an input component then:

```
<sample
"^@validation"="validation"/>
```

Can anyone help me to understand the usage of "^@" notation.

Can JS version: 2.3.27

Comment: What is the version of CanJS are you using? it can help to answer you question!

Comment: @CherifBOUCHELAGHEM Updated in post.

Comment: This is gone in CanJS 4.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is a one-way child-to-parent binding (think of the `^` pointing up from the child property to the parent component). You can find more info in the [{^to-parent} docs](https://v2.canjs.com/docs/can.view.bindings.toParent.html).

`@` (called the “at operator”) is useful when values are functions. In CanJS 2.3 and 3.x, stache will call those functions to get their values by default; `@` bypasses that, and instead uses the function as the value. This is mentioned in the [2.3 expression docs](https://v2.canjs.com/docs/can.stache.expressions.html), but more clearly explained in the [3.x docs](https://v3.canjs.com/doc/can-stache/keys/at.html).